# Quarkus Image: Cannot run program "keytool": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, quarkus, keytool

I have a Java project which runs on Java 11 and uses Quarkus framework. Somewhere within the project's code there is this line:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                        .exec("keytool -keystore " + trustStore.toString() + " -alias postgresql " + "-storepass \""
                                + trustCredentials.toString() + "\" -noprompt -import -file " + caRoot.toString());
```

The above line is using the keytool command to add a cert to the truststore.

The issue comes in when trying build my java project into a Fast-Jar and then run that jar. The Keytool command is not found:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:416) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:313) ~[?:?]
```

I don't quite understand why this would be happening. I know the keytool comes along with the java installation, I have checked, it does appear to be installed on my image. I also understand that the PATH variable may need to be updated. However, on a Linux machine (which my image is base off of), keytool gets installed under /usr/bin and that is part of the path already. As another test I also tried specifying the path of the keytool in the java code, i.e:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                        .exec("/usr/bin/keytool -keystore " ...blah
```

yet still got the same error. Perhaps the issue maybe related to how quarkus builds its images?

This is roughly how i build my Fast Jar Image in my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
- export JOB_CONTAINER_ID=`docker ps -q -f "label=com.gitlab.gitlab-runner.type=build" -f "label=com.gitlab.gitlab-runner.job.id=$CI_JOB_ID"`
      - export TOKEN=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN
      - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
      - |
         docker build -t temp-image-builder -f - . << EOF
         FROM ${DIND_BUILD_IMAGE}
         COPY . /project
         EOF
      - docker run --rm --privileged --name=temp-image-builder --user root -w /project
         -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
         -e "CI_PROJECT_DIR=$CI_PROJECT_DIR" -e "TOKEN=$TOKEN" -e "QUARKUS_PROFILE=$QUARKUS_PROFILE" -e "TAG=$TAG"
         -e "IMAGE_NAME=${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${TAG}" -e "ENFORCE_RELEASE_GATE=on"
         -e "CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" -e "GITLAB_USER_LOGIN=$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN"
         -e "CI_PROJECT_NAME=$CI_PROJECT_NAME" -e "CI_PROJECT_URL=$CI_PROJECT_URL" -e "CI_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID"
         --entrypoint /bin/bash temp-image-builder:latest '-c'
            '
               ./gradlew -Pversion="${TAG}"
                  clean build
                  -Dquarkus.package.type=fast-jar
                  -Dquarkus.profile="${QUARKUS_PROFILE}"
                  -Dquarkus.jib.base-registry-username=gitlab-ci-token -Dquarkus.jib.base-registry-password="$TOKEN"
                  -Dquarkus.container-image.tag="${TAG}"
                  -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true
            '
      - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${TAG}
```

with ${DIND_BUILD_IMAGE} being another image based off a java-11 alpine image.

Trying to solve this has been really frustrating, it seems like such a simple thing but i have had no luck so far. Any suggestions on what may be wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is you caroot defined? `caRoot.toString()`

Comment: Its all defined somewhere, just didn't feel it was necessary to show. I also noticed that its not just the keytool command, its any command i suppose. I tried doing a .exec("ls /") and i got a command not found error

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it really was a PATH issue. I was mistaken about keytool being under usr/bin. Using this tool called ["dive"](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive), i was able to figure out where keytool was located. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it is possible to update to PATH variable to where keytool is located using jib, but at the very least i could run exec and include keytool path (i.e .exec(path/to/tool/keytool ...blah)) and it would run successfully